# BeautifulSoup returns missing information

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am building web scraper to get daily important events on that day from [url](http://www.tarihtebugun.gen.tr/?t=1),
my code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup        

url = "http://www.tarihtebugun.gen.tr/?t=1"

# Get the latest link for the updated news:
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except Exception as err:
    logging.error("Connect: {}, {}".format(err, url))

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
soup = soup.find_all('td', class_='Maddeler')

olaylar = "Tarihte Bugün\n"

for tarih, olay in zip(soup[0::2], soup[1::2]):        
    olaylar = olaylar + "{}-{}\n".format(fx._b(tarih.get_text().strip()), olay.get_text().strip())
```

for the html line:

```
<td align='left' valign='top' class='Maddeler' Style='padding-right:3px;'><a href=http://www.tarihtebugun.gen.tr/türkiye.html />Türkiye</a> Tas Kömürü Kurumu Zonguldak'ta kuruldu.</td>
```

I get

```
<td align='left' valign='top' class='Maddeler' Style='padding-right:3px;'><a href=http://www.tarihtebugun.gen.tr/türkiye.html />Türkiye</a></td>
```

Text after the URL Anchor is missing in BeautifulSoup result. if there is no `<a>` tag, than it works okay.

I can't figure out what is the problem

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want as an output (I don't see that text at all in the link). But if you are after the table, might be easier to use pandas to grab that table, then you can pull out any text you want from the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = "http://www.tarihtebugun.gen.tr/?t=1"

# Get the latest link for the updated news:
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)

    df_max = max([len(x) for x in dfs])
    df = dfs[[i for i, j in enumerate(dfs) if len(j) == df_max][0]]
    df = df.dropna(0, 'all')
    df = df.dropna(1, 'all').reset_index(drop=True)

    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df.iloc[1:,:].reset_index(drop=True)

except Exception as err:
    logging.error("Connect: {}, {}".format(err, url))
```

**Output: Full Table**

```
print (df)
0        Tarih                                              Bilgi
0   14/05/1767  Ýngiliz hükümetinin ithal çaya vergi koymasý ü...
1   14/05/1924    Türkiye Taþ Kömürü Kurumu Zonguldak'ta kuruldu.
2   14/05/1946  Türkiye Sosyalist Partisi kuruldu. Baþkanlýða ...
3   14/05/1948                            Ýsrail devleti kuruldu.
4   14/05/1950  27 yýllýk Cumhuriyet Halk Partisi iktidarý son...
5   14/05/1952  Paris'te toplanan Uluslararasý Basýn Enstitüsü...
6   14/05/1955  Sovyetler Birliði ve Doðu Avrupa'daki sosyalis...
7   14/05/1955  Nedret Gürcan, Dinar'da , Þairler Yapraðý adlý...
8   14/05/1957  Dr. Asým Onat Dünya Týp Cemiyeti baþkanlýðýna ...
9   14/05/1958              Ziya Ademhan 1 yýl hapse mahkum oldu.
10  14/05/1968  Üniversite öðrencileri "NATO'ya Hayýr" haftasý...
11  14/05/1974  12 Mart askeri müdahalesi sýrasýnda tutuklanan...
12  14/05/1984  Yaþar Kemal'in Ýnce Memed romanýný beyaz perde...
13  14/05/1985  Hüsamettin Cindoruk, Doðru Yol Partisi genel b...
14  14/05/1996  Ýstanbul Alibeyköy'de Ýrfan Aðdaþ adlý genç po...
15  14/05/1997  Türk Silahlý Kuvvetleri Kuzey Irak'a yönelik e...
16  14/05/1997  Danýþtay, Bargama köylülerinin siyanürle altýn...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but i get very corrupted output. not as above. I copy paste the code to check. but not functioning same. I will work on it to see if I can figure out what is wrong.